# md raid not mounted by dracut

Tags: centos, lvm, mdadm, software-raid, initramfs

## Background

I'm running Centos 7. Originally, it was running on a single disk that looked something like this:

```
1  200M    EFI System       (/boot/efi)
2  500M    Microsoft basic  (/boot)
3  465.1G  Linux LVM 

LVM VG centos
- LVM LV ext4 centos-root (/)
- LVM LV swap centos-swap (swap)
```

This was just a temporary solution as it was originally supposed to be installed on a Linux software RAID1 array. I got around to migrating it today. This is what it currently looks like:

```
Both new disks have this partition layout:

1  200M    EFI System   (/boot/efi)
2  457.6G  Linux RAID   /dev/md0  RAID1 (for boot and LVM)
3  8G      Linux RAID   /dev/md1  RAID0 (so 16GB total, for swap)

/dev/md0 looks like this:

1  500M  Linux filesystem (/boot)
2  457G  Linux LVM        (centos-root is migrated to this)

LVM now has only one LV, centos-root
```

`/etc/mdadm.conf` looks like this:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=main.centos.local:0 UUID=5b5057b4:4235ba4b:5342dfda:acf63302
   devices=/dev/sda2,/dev/sdb2
ARRAY /dev/md1 level=raid0 num-devices=2 metadata=1.2 name=main.centos.local:1 UUID=f82a8c99:9b391d83:4efc9456:9e9bad98
   devices=/dev/sda3,/dev/sdb3
```

`/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root                   /          xfs    defaults  0 0
UUID=fcb5f82f-ce6b-460b-800f-329e010bc403 /boot      xfs    defaults  0 0
UUID=C532-14AE                            /boot/efi  vfat   umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 0
/dev/md1                                  swap       swap   defaults  0 0
```

`blkid` outputs this (relevant entries only):

```
/dev/sdb1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="C532-14AE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="ed301bbd-c15c-40af-ae75-bf238d0e6270" 
/dev/sda1: SEC_TYPE="msdos" UUID="C532-14AE" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="f3a76412-41a0-4e04-9b04-ad1c159133cf" 
/dev/md0p1: LABEL="boot" UUID="fcb5f82f-ce6b-460b-800f-329e010bc403" TYPE="xfs" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="df8d6481-c6ce-423a-b5d5-205d355e5653" 
/dev/md0p2: UUID="7LfywM-oPHy-MTEt-swlI-EVbZ-opTo-m82E6R" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTLABEL="primary" PARTUUID="19e7f9d5-a955-4036-8338-03a748faa1f6" 
/dev/mapper/centos-root: UUID="deaa9788-b487-4991-adf7-2945788fb6cd" TYPE="xfs"
```

I have a script which automatically mounts the other EFI partition to `/boot/efi_[device]`, and when the kernel is updated, the grub.cfg gets copied to this partition to keep everything in sync.

`/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` are kept in sync by the script (I've verified this), so it shouldn't be an issue that fstab mounts either one to `/boot/efi` (this also means that if one drive was removed due to failure, the system is still guaranteed to boot). I could have put swap in a LV to simplify things, but the RAID0 gets better performance (for what it's worth) and I get an extra 16GB of space.

I migrated the LV from the old drive to the new PV using the following commands:

```
pvcreate /dev/md0p2
vgextend centos /dev/md0p2
pvmove /dev/sdg3
vgreduce centos /dev/sdg3
```

Then I regenerated the initramfs with `dracut` (after backing up the original), and finally regenerated grub.cfg. Afterwards, I mounted the new `/boot` and `/boot/efi` partitions and copied everything over.

## Problem

After disconnecting the old drive and booting, dracut fails to find my RAID arrays, and of course the `/boot` partition and my LVG as well. It appears that it's simply not calling `mdadm --assemble` on `/dev/md0` and `/dev/md`. I'm able to do just that from the `dracut` prompt, after which `lvm_scan` finds my LVG, I can link `/dev/centos/root` to `/dev/root`, and the system continues booting without any problems once exiting the prompt. Everything seems to be exactly where it should be.

There was a kernel update available, so I tried installing it (assuming I messed something up the first time around when regenerating the initramfs and grub.cfg files), but no dice. System still fails in the exact same way. This is true when I boot from either EFI partition manually (as it should be since the two are identical).

[Link to rdsosreport.txt on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/0V2AznTs)

What am I missing here? How do I get dracut to assemble my arrays?

Comment: Did you run dracut with `-a mdraid`option to add the needed files? It might be that due to installed without mdraid, CentOS7 did not include this module by default.

Comment: Didn't work. Either way, I shouldn't be able to assemble the arrays from the dracut prompt if that were the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The dracut documentation implies that any md raid arrays should be automatically assembled, and that the `rd.md.uuid` parameter should only be used if you only want certain arrays assembled as part of the boot process.

It seems that in reality, the arrays are not assembled automatically, and are in fact only assembled when the `rd.md.uuid` parameter is set (for each array that needs to be assembled). It could be that since the `rd.lvm.lv` parameter was already set, that it somehow interfered with `md`, but I don't have the time to test that.

In short, adding `rd.md.uuid` parameters for both of my arrays to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable in `/etc/default/grub`, and then regenerating the grub config fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I know that my (this) comment is valueless, but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

Adding `rd.md=1` and `rd.md.conf=1` and `rd.auto=1` parameter to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` variable in `/etc/default/grub`, and then regenerating the grub config fixed a similar issue of mine. These parameters are zero by default (`dracut.cmdline` documentation does not state it explicitly but they are).

Of course adding `rd.md.uuid` alone also works, because this explicitly starts the required array. But I am lazy, an prefer the general parameters. The `rd.md.uuid` version has the advantage that only the required array starts at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

I use this [mdadm RAID CentOS booting guide](https://realtechtalk.com/CentOS_7_8_cannot_boot_with_with_mdadm_RAID_array_solution-2439-articles) here as I feel there is a lot of missing info on this subject.

What solved my booting problems were two steps, aside from the obvious.
1.) I added rd.auto=1 to /etc/default/grub and updating grub.cfg
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/redhat/grub.cfg
2.) I had to rebuild my initramfs like this:
dracut --add="mdraid" /boot/initramfs-3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64.img 3.10.0-1127.13.1.el7.x86_64 --force

After that I was able to boot but don't forget to edit dracut.conf to add mdraid so all future kernels get it built in.