# Boot Fail - Extend LVM ("root", "/") over RAID 1 (CentOS 7)

Tags: centos, boot, lvm, raid, software-raid

---

**QUESTION:**

CentOS 7 does not boot after we extend a Volume Group (VG) over RAID 1 using another RAID 1. The process we use is demonstrated in *PROCEDURE: Extend LVM ("root", "/") over RAID 1*. What is wrong and/or missing in the process we demonstrate?

---

**CONTEXT:**

We are trying to extend a Volume Group (VG) over two RAID 1 (software) disks using two other RAID 1 (software) disks.

---

**PROBLEM:**

CentOS 7 does not start after we extend a VG (Volume Group).

---

**PROCEDURE: Extend LVM ("root", "/") over RAID 1**

- Format hard drives

Run the following 2 commands to make new MBR partition table on the two added hard drives...

```
parted /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
parted /dev/sdd mklabel msdos
```

Reload "fstab"...

```
mount -a
```

Use the fdisk command to create a new partition on each drive and format them as a Linux raid autodetect file system. First do this on /dev/sdc.

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

Follow these instructions...

- Type "n" to create a new partition;
- Type "p" to select primary partition;
- Type "1" to create /dev/sdb1;
- Press Enter to choose the default first sector;
- Press Enter to choose the default last sector. This partition will span across the entire drive;
- Type "t" and Enter "fd" to set partition type to Linux raid autodetect;
- Type "w" to apply the above changes.

**NOTE:** Follow the same instruction to create a Linux raid autodetect partition on "/dev/sdd".

Now we have two raid devices "/dev/sdc1" and "/dev/sdd1".

- Create RAID 1 logical drive

Execute the following command to create RAID 1...

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --create /dev/md125 --homehost=localhost --name=pv01 --level=mirror --bitmap=internal --consistency-policy=bitmap --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md125 started.
```

Increasing the logical volume

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/md125
  Physical volume "/dev/md125" successfully created.
```

We extend the "centosvg" volume group by adding in the physical volume of "/dev/md125" ("RAID 1") which we created using the "pvcreate" command just before...

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgextend centosvg /dev/md125
  Volume group "centosvg" successfully extended
```

Increase the logical volume with the "lvextend" command - will be taking our original logical volume and extending it over our new disk/partition/physical ("RAID 1") volume of "/dev/md125"...

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvextend /dev/centosvg/root /dev/md125
  Size of logical volume centosvg/root changed from 4.95 GiB (1268 extents) to <12.95 GiB (3314 extents).
  Logical volume centosvg/root successfully resized.
```

Resize the file system using the "xfs_growfs" command in order to make use of this space...

```
[root@localhost ~]# xfs_growfs /dev/centosvg/root
meta-data=/dev/mapper/centosvg-root isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=324608 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1298432, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 1298432 to 3393536
```

- Save our RAID1 configuration

This command updates your boot kernel configuration to match the current state of your system...

```
mdadm --detail --scan > /tmp/mdadm.conf
\cp -v /tmp/mdadm.conf /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Update GRUB configuration so that it knows about the new devices...

```
grub2-mkconfig -o "$(readlink -e /etc/grub2.cfg)"
```

You should run the following command to generate a new "initramfs" image after running the above command...

```
dracut -fv
```

---

**ERROR:**

[image: Boot fail!]

---

**INFRASTRUCTURE/OTHER INFORMATION:**

*lsblk*

```
[root@localhost ~]# lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0    8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                8:1    0    1G  0 part  
│ └─md127             9:127  0 1023M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda2                8:2    0    7G  0 part  
  └─md126             9:126  0    7G  0 raid1 
    ├─centosvg-root 253:0    0    5G  0 lvm   /
    └─centosvg-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdb                   8:16   0    8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                8:17   0    1G  0 part  
│ └─md127             9:127  0 1023M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb2                8:18   0    7G  0 part  
  └─md126             9:126  0    7G  0 raid1 
    ├─centosvg-root 253:0    0    5G  0 lvm   /
    └─centosvg-swap 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
sdc                   8:32   0    8G  0 disk  
sdd                   8:48   0    8G  0 disk  
sr0                  11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

*mdadm --examine /dev/sdc /dev/sdd*

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     16775168 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :     16775168 sectors at         2048 (type fd)
```

*mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1*

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 51a622a9:666c7936:1bf1db43:8029ab06
           Name : localhost:pv01
  Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 13:42:20 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 16764928 sectors (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Array Size : 8382464 KiB (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
    Data Offset : 10240 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=10160 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f95b50e3:eed41b52:947ddbb4:b42a40d6

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan  7 13:43:15 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 9d4c040c - correct
         Events : 25


   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : 51a622a9:666c7936:1bf1db43:8029ab06
           Name : localhost:pv01
  Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 13:42:20 2020
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 16764928 sectors (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Array Size : 8382464 KiB (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
    Data Offset : 10240 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=10160 sectors, after=0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : bcb18234:aab93a6c:80384b09:c547fdb9

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Tue Jan  7 13:43:15 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 16 sectors
       Checksum : 40ca1688 - correct
         Events : 25


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

*cat /proc/mdstat*

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] 
md125 : active raid1 sdd1[1] sdc1[0]
      8382464 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md126 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      7332864 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md127 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      1047552 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 0/1 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

*mdadm --detail /dev/md125*

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --detail /dev/md125
/dev/md125:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Tue Jan  7 13:42:20 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 8382464 (7.99 GiB 8.58 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Tue Jan  7 13:43:15 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : bitmap

              Name : localhost:pv01
              UUID : 51a622a9:666c7936:1bf1db43:8029ab06
            Events : 25

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       8       49        1      active sync   /dev/sdd1
```

*fdisk -l*

```
[root@localhost ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000f2ab2

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2101247     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         2101248    16777215     7337984   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0002519d

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048     2101247     1049600   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         2101248    16777215     7337984   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdc: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x0007bd31

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048    16777215     8387584   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdd: 8589 MB, 8589934592 bytes, 16777216 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00086fef

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1            2048    16777215     8387584   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md127: 1072 MB, 1072693248 bytes, 2095104 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md126: 7508 MB, 7508852736 bytes, 14665728 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centosvg-root: 5318 MB, 5318377472 bytes, 10387456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/centosvg-swap: 2147 MB, 2147483648 bytes, 4194304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/md125: 8583 MB, 8583643136 bytes, 16764928 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

*df -h*

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                   484M     0  484M   0% /dev
tmpfs                      496M     0  496M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                      496M  6.8M  489M   2% /run
tmpfs                      496M     0  496M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/centosvg-root  5.0G  1.4G  3.7G  27% /
/dev/md127                1020M  164M  857M  17% /boot
tmpfs                      100M     0  100M   0% /run/user/0
```

*vgdisplay*

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               centosvg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               6.99 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              1790
  Alloc PE / Size       1780 / 6.95 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       10 / 40.00 MiB
  VG UUID               6mKxWb-KOIe-fW1h-zukQ-f7aJ-vxD5-hKAaZG
```

*pvscan*

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvscan
  PV /dev/md126   VG centosvg        lvm2 [6.99 GiB / 40.00 MiB free]
  PV /dev/md125   VG centosvg        lvm2 [7.99 GiB / 7.99 GiB free]
  Total: 2 [14.98 GiB] / in use: 2 [14.98 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
```

*lvdisplay*

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centosvg/swap
  LV Name                swap
  VG Name                centosvg
  LV UUID                o5G6gj-1duf-xIRL-JHoO-ux2f-6oQ8-LIhdtA
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2020-01-06 13:22:08 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                2.00 GiB
  Current LE             512
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/centosvg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                centosvg
  LV UUID                GTbGaF-Wh4J-1zL3-H7r8-p5YZ-kn9F-ayrX8U
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time localhost, 2020-01-06 13:22:09 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                4.95 GiB
  Current LE             1268
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     8192
  Block device           253:0
```

*cat /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt*

[image: cat /run/initramfs/rdsosreport.txt]

Thank you! **=D**

**[Refs.:** https://4fasters.com.br/2017/11/12/lpic-2-o-que-e-e-para-que-serve-o-dracut/ , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152249/61742 , 
https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-debian-etch-p2 , 
https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-lvm-on-top-of-software-raid1-rhel-fedora , 
https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/linux-software-raid-1-setup , 
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk/ **]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was occurring for the reasons below...

> The dracut documentation implies that any md raid arrays should be
>   automatically assembled, and that the "rd.md.uuid" parameter should
>   only be used if you only want certain arrays assembled as part of the
>   boot process.
>
> It seems that in reality, the arrays are not assembled automatically,
>   and are in fact only assembled when the "rd.md.uuid" parameter is set
>   (for each array that needs to be assembled). It could be that since
>   the "rd.lvm.lv" parameter was already set, that it somehow interfered
>   with "md", but I don't have the time to test that.
>
> In short, adding rd.md.uuid parameters for both of my arrays to the
>   "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" variable in "/etc/default/grub", and then
>   regenerating the grub config fixed the issue for me.

That is, to the boot works the new array (new "RAID 1") needs to be entered in the "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" parameter since it will be part of "root" ("/").

For more details, see the section **Save our "RAID 1" configuration and adjust CentOS boot** in the complete procedure below.

**[Refs.:** https://4fasters.com.br/2017/11/12/lpic-2-o-que-e-e-para-que-serve-o-dracut/ , 
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=49541#p256406 , 
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=51937&start=10#p220414 , 
https://forums.centos.org/viewtopic.php?t=72667 , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152249/61742 , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/267773/61742 , 
https://www.howtoforge.com/set-up-raid1-on-a-running-lvm-system-debian-etch-p2 , 
https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-lvm-on-top-of-software-raid1-rhel-fedora , 
https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/linux-software-raid-1-setup , 
https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk/ **]**

---

**Extend LVM ("root", "/") over RAID 1**

- Format hard drives

After physically adding the two new disks run the command below to list all disks/ devices (including RAID subsystems)...

```
lsblk
```

**NOTE:** In our case the devices will be called "sdc" and "sdd" and by default will be in the paths "/dev/sdc" and "/dev/sdd" respectively.

Run the following 2 commands to make new MBR partition table on the two added hard drives...

```
parted /dev/sdc mklabel msdos
parted /dev/sdd mklabel msdos
```

**IMPORTANT:** Any data that may be on both disks will be destroyed.

Reload "fstab"...

```
mount -a
```

Use the "fdisk" command to create a new partition on each drive and format them as a "Linux raid autodetect" file system. First do this on "/dev/sdc"...

```
fdisk /dev/sdc
```

Follow these instructions...

- Type "n" to create a new partition;
- Type "p" to select primary partition;
- Type "1" to create /dev/sdb1;
- Press Enter to choose the default first sector;
- Press Enter to choose the default last sector. This partition will span across the entire drive;
- We need to change the partition type, so type "t";
- Enter "fd" to set partition type to "Linux raid autodetect";
- Type "w" to apply the above changes.

**NOTE:** Follow the same instruction to create a Linux raid autodetect partition on "/dev/sdd".

- Create RAID 1 logical drive

Execute the following command to create the "RAID 1"...

> **IMPORTANT:**
>
> - For the name of the "array" we will assign "/dev/md/pv01" since the highest order identified for these devices in our case is "pv00" (note
>     the output of the command "mdadm --detail --scan"). The array name
>     "/dev/md/pv01" will also be a symbolic path to a "/dev/md12X" device.
>     This path is automatically generated by "mdadm" (command below). The
>     path "/dev/md12X" represents a new device, which in turn represents
>     the devices "/dev/sdc1" and "/dev/sdd1" ("RAID 1"). You can later
>     confirm what the device name is actually ("/dev/md125", "/dev/md126",
>     "/dev/md127", etc ...) with the `ls /dev/md*` command or the `readlink
>     -f /dev/md/pv01` command;
> - The "array" name "/dev/md/pv01" follows the current naming "pattern" used by CentOS. We recommend using it.

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --create /dev/md/pv01 --name=pv01 --level=mirror --bitmap=internal --consistency-policy=bitmap --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
mdadm: Note: this array has metadata at the start and
    may not be suitable as a boot device.  If you plan to
    store '/boot' on this device please ensure that
    your boot-loader understands md/v1.x metadata, or use
    --metadata=0.90
Continue creating array? y
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md/pv01 started.
```

Create the PV (Physical Volumes) to extent our LVM...

```
[root@localhost ~]# pvcreate /dev/md/pv01
  Physical volume "/dev/md/pv01" successfully created.
```

We extend the "centosvg" volume group by adding in the PV (Physical Volumes) of "/dev/md/pv01" ("RAID 1") which we created using the "pvcreate" command just above...

**TIP:** To find out the name of the target VG (Volume Group) use the command "vgdisplay" observing the value of the attribute "VG Name" which in our case is "centosvg".

```
[root@localhost ~]# vgextend centosvg /dev/md/pv01
  Volume group "centosvg" successfully extended
```

Increase the LV (Logical Volume) with the "lvextend" command over our new PV (Physical Volumes) "/dev/md/pv01"...

**TIP:** To find out the target Logical Volume (LV) path use the "lvdisplay" command looking at the value of the "LV Path" attribute which in our case is "/dev/centosvg/root".

```
[root@localhost ~]# lvextend /dev/centosvg/root /dev/md/pv01
  Size of logical volume centosvg/root changed from 4.95 GiB (1268 extents) to <12.95 GiB (3314 extents).
  Logical volume centosvg/root successfully resized.
```

Resize the file system inside "/dev/centosvg/root" LV (Logical Volume) using the "xfs_growfs" command in order to make use of the new space...

**TIP:** Use the same path as the LV (Logical Volume) used above that in our case is "/dev/centosvg/root".

```
[root@localhost ~]# xfs_growfs /dev/centosvg/root
meta-data=/dev/mapper/centosvg-root isize=512    agcount=4, agsize=324608 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
         =                       crc=1        finobt=0 spinodes=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1298432, imaxpct=25
         =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=1
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data blocks changed from 1298432 to 3393536
```

- Save our "RAID 1" configuration and adjust CentOS boot

Update your boot kernel configuration to match the current state of your system.

Run the command...

```
[root@localhost ~]# mdadm --detail --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/boot metadata=1.2 name=localhost:boot UUID=50ed66ef:6fb373da:5690ac4b:4fb82a45
ARRAY /dev/md/pv00 metadata=1.2 name=localhost:pv00 UUID=283a4a43:43c85816:55c6adf0:ddcbfb2b
ARRAY /dev/md/pv01 metadata=1.2 name=localhost.localdomain:pv01 UUID=e5feec81:20d5e154:9a1e2dce:75a03c71
```

... and look at the line containing the array/device "/dev/md/pv01" (our case).

Open the file "/etc/mdadm.conf"...

```
vi /etc/mdadm.conf
```

... and at the end add a line as below...

MODEL

```
ARRAY [NEW_ARRAY_NAME] level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=[NEW_ARRAY_UUID]
```

EXAMPLE

```
ARRAY /dev/md/pv01 level=raid1 num-devices=2 UUID=e5feec81:20d5e154:9a1e2dce:75a03c71
```

Open the file "/etc/default/grub"...

```
vi /etc/default/grub
```

... and look for the parameter "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX".

In the value of the parameter "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX" look for another parameter "rd.lvm.lv" that represents the "root" partition as below...

MODEL

```
rd.lvm.lv=[VG_NAME]/[LV_NAME]
```

EXAMPLE

```
rd.lvm.lv=centosvg/root
```

... adding to this "rd.lvm.lv" one more "rd.md.uuid" - which in this case is the same as "[NEW_ARRAY_UUID]" used above - as below ...

MODEL

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=[LV_NAME] rd.md.uuid=283a4a43:43c85816:55c6adf0:ddcbfb2b rd.md.uuid=50ed66ef:6fb373da:5690ac4b:4fb82a45 rd.md.uuid=[NEW_ARRAY_UUID] rd.lvm.lv=centosvg/swap rhgb quiet"
```

EXAMPLE

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto rd.lvm.lv=centosvg/root rd.md.uuid=283a4a43:43c85816:55c6adf0:ddcbfb2b rd.md.uuid=50ed66ef:6fb373da:5690ac4b:4fb82a45 rd.md.uuid=e5feec81:20d5e154:9a1e2dce:75a03c71 rd.lvm.lv=centosvg/swap rhgb quiet"
```

Update GRUB configuration so that it knows about the new devices...

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

You should run the following command to generate a new "initramfs" image after running the above command...

```
dracut -fv
```

Finally reboot...

```
reboot
```

**IMPORTANT:** Although rebooting is not mandatory for the process to work, we recommend doing it to check for possible failures.